# passing variables with forfiles command

Tags: variables, batch-file

I've searched on here for a while but can't find a solution that works.

I'm attempting to run the following (test.bat):

```
SET CURRENT_DATE=%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
SET DOCSRC = "C:\scripts\e2Vault\docdata"
SET DOCSTAGING = "C:\Scripts\e2Vault\staging"
SET LOGFILE = "C:\Scripts\e2Vault\log files"
SET DOCPROCESS = "C:\scripts\e2Vault\process"
SET DOCREMOVED = "C:\scripts\e2Vault\removed"

forfiles /p "%DOCSRC%" /m *.drd /d -547 /c "cmd /c echo @path && Move @file "%DOCSTAGING%"" >> %LOGFILE%\e2Vault_archive_%CURRENT_DATE%.log
```

But it's giving me the following output without moving the files or logging:

```
C:\scripts\e2Vault>forfiles /p "" /m *.drd /d -547 /c "cmd /c echo @path && Move @file """  1>>\e2Vault_archive_2012_06_19.log
ERROR: Value for '/p' option cannot be empty.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

I have tried using """ and \" in various configurations but every one I try just displays the quotes where the variable should be.

As you can probably see I'm testing this but the live system paths for variables have spaces in them so I need to get it working.

If I do not use the SET variables and put in the absolute paths the script works.

Really hoping someone can point out what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have spaces around the `=` in `set` commands. You're creating environment variables the end with a space there.

```
SET CURRENT_DATE=%date:~6,4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%
SET DOCSRC=C:\scripts\e2Vault\docdata
SET DOCSTAGING=C:\Scripts\e2Vault\staging
SET LOGFILE=C:\Scripts\e2Vault\log files
SET DOCPROCESS=C:\scripts\e2Vault\process
SET DOCREMOVED=C:\scripts\e2Vault\removed
```

would be the correct way.